# ERROR: Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make a simple example of persistence using JPA with Hibernate as provider. I'm using MySQL as database. But I'm getting this error:

```
Hibernate: insert into person (NAME, DTYPE) values (?, 'person')
dez 21, 2014 8:35:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
dez 21, 2014 8:35:01 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 22 more
```

Here my codes

1) Test.java

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ExampleJPA");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {

        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("pessoa " + i);
        em.persist(p);
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
}
```

2) Person.java

```
public class Person {

private int id;
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

3) persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence            
http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="ExampleJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/person.xml</mapping-file>   
    <class>Person</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gerenciador"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

4) Person.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm     
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

 <entity class="Person" name="person">
    <table name="person"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id">
            <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="name">
            <column name="NAME" length="255"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have inheritance in your hibernate model?  The name of the discriminator column in hibernate defaults to "DTYPE" hence the [confusion](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/). Go through your project model again and reply back.

Comment: Hello. No. I don't. Just the class Person as you can see in the code without any inheritance. It's a very simple example where I want to persist the name of a person in the database. It works if I use hibernate specific mapping and change the JPA's EntityManager to Hibernate's Session.

Comment: What is your hibernate and jpa version?

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.7 and JPA 2.1

Comment: What don't you use JPA annotations to map your java model instead of xml? Much simpler to understand.

Comment: Andy. I know, I used annotations and it worked, but I'm learning hibernate and jpa and I'd like to know how to do it in annotations and XML as well.